# If statement in hover function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/2065/)

Is this how you would put an if statement in a hover function?

```
$( ".nn" ).hover(
  function() {
   if($(this).find('p').height() > $(this).height())
   {
    $( this ).css( "height","auto" ).removeClass("oh");
   }
  }, function() {

    $( this ).css( "height","6em" ).addClass("oh");

  }
);
```

Since the if statement is only for the first function (mouseover), does the function still trigger on the mouseout function? Is it possible to wrap the if statement around the entire hover function,something like this:

```
    $( ".nn" ).hover(

    function() {
    if($(this).find('p').height() > $(this).height())
    {
       $( this ).css( "height","auto" ).removeClass("oh");

      }, function() {

        $( this ).css( "height","6em" ).addClass("oh");

      }
    }
    );
```

HTML

Very long text

```
<div class="nn oh"><p>short text</p></div>
```

Comment: Hover accepts an in/out handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave, so use just one handler and check event type inside it. Cannot post code coz im on tablet, sorry

Comment: What you try to achieve? Look to works fine here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/2066/)

Comment: @RedGiant: The if statement work fine in the first code?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Alex and Wolff. @Jean-Paul Yes, the if statement works fine. The second div block doesn't have any effect on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to your questions.

**1.** `Does the function still trigger on the mouseout function?`

Yes, because you bound mouseleave event, it will still fire.

**2.** `Is it possible to wrap the if statement around the entire hover function?`

No, you can wrap two separate callback functions with the same `if` block. You could however take another approach and bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` manually (since `hover` is just a sugar for these two events). It would look like this:

```
$(".nn").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('p').height() > $(this).height()) {
        if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
            $(this).css("height", "auto").removeClass("oh");
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("height", "6em").addClass("oh");
        }
    }
});
```

But then you would realize that this is **not** what you need, because in this case you will never get into `else` branch, since the condition:

```
$(this).find('p').height() > $(this).height()
```

will be false after the `mouseenter` event.

---

**Finally**. Maybe optimal approach here is to go with just simple CSS without any javascript.

To limit initial block height you would use `max-height: 6em`. Then `.nn:hover` rule would take care of expansion with `max-height: inherit; height: auto;`.

```css
.nn {
    border-bottom: 0.8em solid #B1B3BE;
    font-size: 25px;
    max-height: 6em;
    margin: 6% 0;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 0.3em solid #6F87B3;
    width:40%;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nn:hover {
    max-height: inherit;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="nn oh">
    <p>ddddddddddddd dsffffffffff fffffffff dffffff ffff fgdgfdfgddfg ffgdfdgdfgdfg dfggdfdgfd fdsdgfdfgdgf fdgfdgf gf</p>
</div>
<div class="nn oh">
    <p>ddddddddddddd</p>
</div>
```